# Image that fits height of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve something similiar to [this](http://www.tybaltetmercutio.com/) kind of thing where there is an image which fills window until you scroll down. I really have no idea how to achieve this. I'm guessing through jQuery? I really haven't been able to find anything. My knowledge of jQuery is limited, though I do have an understanding of Javascript.

Thank you for any help.

---

Comment: A background image of a large div is the simplest method.  If you want parallax, use a parallax library.

Comment: Another example using the body and the modern 'background-size' - http://jsfiddle.net/anXHU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery or Javascript at all. You need a full screen div, with a background image.

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h95f/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="fullscreenimg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fullscreenimg {

   background-image:url(IMAGEURL);

   background-size:cover;

   width:100%;

   height:100%;

}
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out in comment, this will work in modern browsers and several back, but it won't work in older versions (6-8) of IE.

An alternative for older browsers would be to use a `<img>`, and position it absolutely, with `top`, `bottom',`left`, and`right`, all being set to`0`. This will stretch it though, not resize.

Comment: ***Note:*** background-size is not implemented in IE below 9. http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: Oh my goodness I feel so silly. I'd been doing this for body backgrounds and it never occurred to me to do it for a div. This is my first time playing about with web-coding for a while. Obviously I'm a bit rusty haha! Thank you so much!

Comment: Eh, we all take a bit to get back into the swing of things. :) If it helped, could you mark it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Done. :) Should I need to specify a "position" property for it to work? It only turns up if I do and it's just complicating my layout because I want to add content underneath it. :(

Comment: You shouldn't need to. In the JSFiddle that I attached, it doesn't have a position specified. If it's not showing up, there may be something else affecting it. I can take a look if you'd like to link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `vw` as a `width` unit.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/zyc9p/)**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1024x768" />
```

---

```
img{
    width:100vw;
}
```

vw is viewport width.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about vw!

Comment: This is an interesting idea, I haven't done much with `vw`. One disadvantage here would be the height though, right? You'll either have a variable height, or a stretched image?

Comment: Should have probably specified I needed it to scale!

Comment: @AndyM: Shorter image, yes, Stretched? No. But using a background-image will have effects on the height too, No ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to answer this. I am unsure which answer you need so Ill provide both.

You can make an image cover the veiwport height, and then you can make it cover window height.

The first way is the trickier way, but still simpler than youd think.
HTML

```
<img src="whatever.png" class="bam">
```

CSS

```
.bam {height:100%; width:100%;}
```

jQuery

```
var fullheight = $(document).height();
$(".bam").css("height", fullheight);
```

The following shows how to make it at full window size.
[Full size window stretch - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NswR/2/)

This one shows the view port version.
[Viewport stretch image - fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NswR/1/)